# three.js PointsMaterial performance slow - big sprites/shapes slow down performance

Tags: javascript, performance, three.js, webgl

I'm working on a point cloud of about 60.000 vertices.

If I render the cloud "viewing it small" performance is ok, but when I "zoom in" and I see big sprites / planes / points on screen, performance drops.

This happens using a `PointsMaterial` or a `RawShaderMaterial`, a `Points` object or an `instancedBufferGeometry` mesh.

It looks like when rendering a single large shape that covers most of the canvas, performance drops.

Performance drops worse if the points have a transparent texture.

I remember having a similar problem while rendering big overlapping transparent images in Processing.

Comment: can you make a fiddle?

Comment: depth test is on, no textures used.

Comment: Why is this being downvoted it's a legitimate question?

Answer (score 5):

As Sedenion mentioned you're most likely fill rate bound. That means you're drawing too many pixels.

A GPU can only draw so fast. A average non-gamer GPU can only draw 6-10 screens full of pixels at 60 frames a second. If you draw more pixels than that it will run too slow even of those are simple pixels (in other words even if you have simple shaders). For a normal 3D scene usually you have a depth test enabled. By drawing the closest things first the depth buffer will prevent things in the back from being drawn which helps speed things up. For sprites though usually depth testing is not used. This means every pixel from every sprite is drawn even if they overlap. If you add up the number of pixels getting drawn you'll see you are quickly drawing too many pixels.

Here's a simple example that just draws a 2048x2048 `POINT` in a solid color, no textures. An extremely simple shader. Drag the slider to the right to draw more points. In my 2014 Macbook Pro it can only draw about 12 points at that size before it can no longer run at 60fps. Different GPUs will be able to draw more or less.

```js
const vs = `
void main() {
  gl_Position = vec4(0, 0, 0, 1);
  gl_PointSize = 4000.0;
}
`
const fs = `
void main() {
  gl_FragColor = vec4(1./256., 0, 0, 1./256.);
}
`;

const gl = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("webgl");
const programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fs]);

let numPoints = 1;
const inputElem = document.querySelector('input');
const numPointsElem = document.querySelector('#numpoints');
const fpsElem = document.querySelector('#fps');
const numPixElem = document.querySelector('#numpix');
const pointSizeElem = document.querySelector('#ps');
const pointSize = Math.min(2048, gl.getParameter(gl.ALIASED_POINT_SIZE_RANGE)[1]);
pointSizeElem.textContent = `${pointSize}x${pointSize}`;


inputElem.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  updateValue(e.target.value);
});

function updateValue(value) {
  numPointsElem.textContent = value;
  numPixElem.textContent = frmt(value * pointSize * pointSize);
  numPoints = value;
};

updateValue(1);

let then = 0;
function render(now) {
  const deltaTime = now - then;
  then = now;
  const fps = 1000 / deltaTime;
  fpsElem.textContent = fps.toFixed(1);
  
  gl.enable(gl.BLEND);
  gl.blendFunc(gl.ONE, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
  gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);
  gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, numPoints);

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
requestAnimationFrame(render);

function frmt(v) {
  return [].map.call(v.toString(), a => a).reverse().map((a, n) => { return a + (n % 3 === 0 && n > 1 ? ',' : ''); }).reverse().join('');
}
```

```css
html { box-sizing: border-box; }
*, *:after, *:before { box-sizing: inherit; }
body {  margin: 0; font-family: monospace; }
canvas { width: 100vw; height: 100vh; display: block; }
#ui { 
  padding: 1em;
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  color: white; 
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); 
  width: 100vw;
};
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<canvas width="2048" height="2048"></canvas>
<div id="ui">
  <div><input type="range" min="1" max="500" value="1"></div>
  <div>number of points: <span id="numpoints">1</span></div>
  <div>point size: <span id="ps"></span></div>
  <div>number of pixels being drawn per frame: <span id="numpix"></span></div>
  <div>frames per second: <span id="fps"></span></div>
</div>
```

There is no "easy" solution. You need to find a way to draw less pixels some way or another. Turn on depth testing and make your points not blend might be on solution to help. Sorting your points front to back after turning on depth testing would also help.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Can this behavior eventually cause the "rats!..." in chrome?

Comment: ... if it takes too long to render? When i mess up a shader, and many many things render on top of each other, my browser crashes. As soon as the position works, the same amount of draw calls, the same amount of geometry renders at 60fps. I wonder if it is the overdraw and what happens when thousands or millions of triangles are zfighting in the exact same spot.

Comment: yes, chrome will kill WebGL if a single draw call takes too long. Windows will also do this at an OS level and reboot the GPU. Maybe someday GPUs will be preemptable like CPUs but not today

Answer (score 2):

This is not directly related to Three.js, more to WebGL, and more generally to the GPU... You'll observe similar behavior with OpenGL or DirectX. The simple answer is: Your GPU needs to compute then draw some things, and this takes time.

Now lets take a look at some details. I cannot guarantee that your slowdown problem is directly related to what I'll explain, but this is some clues:

1. The more the pixels the GPU has to draw, the more it take time, this means that a simple point-sprite will take longer to draw if it covers the full canvas area, than if it is 3 or 4 pixels wide.
2. Since you try to draw "clouds", I suspect you disabled the depth test, to allow all sprites to be drawn each above the previous one by transparency. This mean the GPU must draws the same pixels on the canvas multiple times, each time with blend equation, for each sprite that covers a part of the canvas.
3. If each sprite has a texture, you add to the point 1. and 2. the texel processing, with texture filtering, mipmap, etc.

You have to tests by yourself where the main bottleneck is. Sometimes, there is nothing you can do and you have to compose within hardware limitations, by reducing sprite count, etc.

Comment: in my test I kept depth test and write on.

1. yes, that's true, but if I draw the same geometry as a mesh instead of a point cloud performance is good, and the screen is still covered the same percentage.

2. as I said no, depth test is enabled (square Points).
But yes, with depth test off, obviously performance is worse.

3. with a texture on performance is worse, but I am testing without textures.

I suppose, considering what you said, that also if I see a little part of the Point on screen, gpu still draws the full Point, then draws the other ones on, etc.

Comment: No, the GPU is not supposed to draw pixels which are out of the frame buffer (canvas). If you see only a small corner of the Point, it should only comput pixels for this small corner (but go know what driver does !).
Unfortunately, I don't know THREE.js very well, but I am pretty sure your performance issue is not THREE.js specific. So maybe it is related to the "Point-Sprite" implementation of WebGL or CG driver which maybe does weird computs when pointSize exceed some value. (i know some drivers limits this value to 64, this forced me to workaround by using an alternative to Point-Sprite).

Comment: Well, I think it's more something about that size limitation, because things go smooth until I reach a certain size.
And it's the only bottleneck I didn't know about so I didn't test it.